# How to force maven release plugin to use previous release dependencies?

Tags: jenkins, default, versioning, mode, maven-release-plugin

I need some help about the maven release plugin !

**FIRST**

I encountered an issue that is obstructing my development on Jenkins.

After installing the maven-release-plugin on Jenkins I've tested it.

The fact is that for a project without any dependencies, the plugin works
 well.

But since I have some project dependencies it doesn't. Indeed after
 selecting the "Default versioning mode" as "Specify version(s)" ,when I
 save he configuration and try to perform maven release build, the "Default
 versioning mode" parameter keeps its state, whatever I change it to and
 simply goes back to ''none'' state. There is no way to modify it !!!

My main goal here is to specify my release version of a dependency and
 this is what the "Default versioning mode" is done for because
 maven-release-plugin can't work with SNAPSHOT dependencies !!

**SECONDLY**

Finally to solve this problem I downgraded the maven release plugin to the 0.7.1 version and now I can select the default versioning mode :D.

But the second issue I faced is that I want to release a job which depends on other one.

Project B ---------> Project A

```
      depends on
```

The fact is I released the Project A in a 0.0.X version.

Now I would like to use/implement this Project A release during the release of the Project B because I don't want any SNAPSHOT dependencies in my released projects !!

I also tried using versions-maven-plugin but the use of both those plugin seems not to work together ... Am I wrong ?

**All I want to do is working while using the cmd !!**
Anyone encountered this problem yet ? is there a solution to it ?

JENKINS 1.596 & maven-release-plugin 0.7.1